# Visual C++ error "cannot convert parameter 1 from 'HANDLE' to 'HANDLE &'"

Tags: c++, c++-cli, visual-c++-2010

I am very new in visual c++ and I meet a problem in my development with some provided API(.lib).

Here's my code:

in header file

```
ref class RFID{
public:
   int connect(char* p);
private:
   HANDLE port;
}
```

in cpp file

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "RFID.h"
int RFID::connect(char* p){
   return RmuOpenAndConnect(port,p,0);
}
```

The error line is:
`error C2664: 'RmuOpenAndConnect' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'HANDLE' to 'HANDLE &'`

Since I am very new in visual c++ and I don't know how to solve with this error, it seems that  the parameter is not just an address of "HANDLE" so that I don't know how to soft it.

Thanks for any help.

Edit:
Sorry that I add the details in comment.
In header file, RmuOpenAndConnect is defined as following:

```
int WINAPI RmuOpenAndConnect (HANDLE &hCom, char* cPort, UCHAR flagCrc);
```

Because I want to use Thread in my program(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.parameterizedthreadstart.aspx), and it seems the class should be a "ref class" so I did.

Comment: Is that your actual code?

Comment: the function "RmuOpenAndConnect()" is an API provided by others. I am developing an demo program of a RFID card reader.

Since it's a .lib & .dll file, so that I can not read the actual code of the API

Comment: It would have been better if you had shown the signature of `RmuOpenAndConnect`

Comment: Interesting preamble to your `class` declaration.

Comment: in header file: int WINAPI RmuOpenAndConnect (HANDLE &hCom, char* cPort, UCHAR flagCrc);

Comment: Since I want to use thread in my program(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.parameterizedthreadstart.aspx). It seems that the class have to define as a ref class so that I did so.

Comment: @chongman Don't post it as a comment, add it to the question.

Comment: Again, show the function prototype for `RmuOpenAndConnect` in the header file. Copy it *exactly*  and put it in your question, include the whole prototype, including the semicolon please.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5966379/passing-a-handle-variable-to-an-unmanaged-dll-in-c-cli

Comment: @WhozCraig I belive you were looking for tag [tag:c++-cli], not for [tag:cli].

Comment: @Angew likely yes. I'm officially up way too late. thanks for the sharp eyes.

Comment: @WhozCraig `cli` in the sense of `c++-cli` is a pet peeve of mine, that's why I noticed :-)

Comment: @Angew I'll hold no inhibitions in saying I think its one of the most hideous and dreadful things MS ever did to the language, and they would have made a ton of people happier had they spent the wad-o-cash bringing their tools to standard compliance sooner rather than the current "much" later. Sry if that offends anyone.

Comment: @WhozCraig +1. Id's say that if people actually understood C++/CLI is a **different** language than C++ (just like C and C++ are different), it wouldn't be so bad. Of course, such knowledge will never spread wide enough (and the name sure doesn't help).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `HANDLE port` is member of managed class, which is subject of garbage collection. Reference to managed class member cannot be used, because class instance can change its address. You can use local variable to fix this:

```
int RFID::connect(char* p){
   HANGLE h = port;
   int n = RmuOpenAndConnect(h,p,0);
   port = h;    // in the case RmuOpenAndConnect changed the handle
   return n;
}
```

Comment: It works, thanks you!

Also thanks anyone who joined this discussion.